# INADDR_ANY details

Tags: winapi, sockets

what will happen if I use `INADDR_ANY` for a socket? Will it receive all traffic from all local interfaces that are related to my computer or everything that are transferred through my interfaces? It is very important for networks using HUB!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically neither.  Read the documentation on [`bind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN) for further details.

Comment: I want to sniff my network interfaces and I'm using a thread for each IP, but I want to use INADDR_ANY to use only a thread that recv all packets? but it just waits on "recv"! Any idea?

Comment: I have to use both INADDR_ANY and SIO_RCVALL options, right? But SIO_RCVALL is just for 1 interface :/