# Sniff all network interfaces

Tags: sockets, networking, sniffing

I've written a program that uses sockets to capture packets on network interfaces. First I gather all IPs of my machine using **gethostbyname**, then bind a raw socket to each ip with **SOCK_RAW**, **IPPROTO_IP** and **SIO_RCVALL** options. A thread is executed for each IP that calls **recv** on the appropriate socket (one socket for each ip). This program works fine.

But I found a special address named **INADDR_ANY**. MSDN says **SIO_RCVALL** cannot be used with INADDR_ANY, it's [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The socket also must be bound to an
>   explicit local IPv4 or IPv6 interface,
>   which means that you cannot bind to
>   INADDR_ANY or in6addr_any.

Is it possible to monitor and capture all packets (packets related to the local computer and not packets of other computers) with one socket?

Thanks

Comment: Is this pretty much the same as your previous question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5217827/inaddr-any-details  Why didn't you just edit that?

Comment: It's not just the same! and do do you know answer of any of them?

Comment: Just keep in mind that a raw socket using type IPPROTO_IP will *only* collect IP traffic. It will not collect other network-level protocols, e.g., ICMP, IGMP, etc., or lower-level protocols, e.g., ARP. If you are trying to generate network statistics, you'll need to use something like the pcap library that will get *everything* from the network.

Answer (score 2):

`INADDR_ANY` means "I don't care which local address," **not** "All local addresses."

#### From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx):

> If an application does not care what local address is assigned, specify the constant value `INADDR_ANY` for an IPv4 local address or the constant value `in6addr_any` for an IPv6 local address in the **`sa_data`** member of the *name* parameter. This allows the underlying service provider to use any appropriate network address, potentially simplifying application programming in the presence of *multihomed* hosts (that is, hosts that have more than one network interface and address).

Comment: Then can the OP capture all received and sent packets with a RAW socket bounded to INADDR_ANY ?